# How does `almost_equals` function of Shapely treat the starting point and errors?

Tags: python, polygon, shapely

Here are polygons with the the same set of points but different starting points/rounding error but still the same direction.

```
poly1 = Polygon([(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)])
poly2 = Polygon([(0,1),(1,1),(1,0),(0,0)])
poly3 = Polygon([(0,1),(1,1.00000001),(1,0),(0,0)])
poly4 = Polygon([(0,0),(0,1),(1,1.00000001),(1,0)])
```

Issue 1: `poly1.almost_equals(poly2)` returns `False` but `poly1.equals(poly2)` returns `True`. So `equals` can handle different starting point but `almost_equals` can not.

Issue 2: `poly1.almost_equals(poly3)` returns `False` but `poly1.almost_equals(poly4)` returns `True`. So `almost_equals` can handle rounding errors but still not different starting point.

Is this how the `almost_equals` function supposed to behave? I think Polygons with different starting points are still the same Polygon and should be treated so. Are there convenient way to solve this problem? I have a complicated custom solution but am wondering if such operation has been implemented in Shapely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is an expected behavior. It is not clearly stated in [the documentation](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.almost_equals) but you can find it in the [docstring](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/53c9cf6c48a7717f45581c8e40b1bf5f205ae728/shapely/geometry/base.py#L801-L808) of the function:

> ```
> def almost_equals(self, other, decimal=6):
>     """Returns True if geometries are equal at all coordinates to a
>     specified decimal place
>
>     Refers to approximate coordinate equality, which requires coordinates be
>     approximately equal and in the same order for all components of a geometry.
>     """
>     return self.equals_exact(other, 0.5 * 10**(-decimal))
> ```

Currently, there is no any other function that you could use to solve your problem. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/889) on GitHub where the future of `almost_equals` is discussed. So, probably, soon a new convenient functionality will be introduced. And, meanwhile, you could use several workarounds:

1. Calculate [`symmetric_difference`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.symmetric_difference) of two polygons and compare the resulting area with some minimum threshold.
   E.g.:

   ```
   def almost_equals(polygon, other, threshold):
       # or (polygon ^ other).area < threshold
       return polygon.symmetric_difference(other).area < threshold

   almost_equals(poly1, poly3, 1e-6)  # True
   ```
2. Normalize both polygons first and then use the `almost_equals`. To normalize them you could, for example, [`orient`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.geometry.polygon.orient) the vertices of the borders counter-clockwise and then order the vertices so that the first vertex of each polygon would be the lowest and the leftmost comparing to other vertices.
   E.g.:

   ```
   from shapely.geometry.polygon import orient


   def normalize(polygon):

       def normalize_ring(ring):
           coords = ring.coords[:-1]
           start_index = min(range(len(coords)), key=coords.__getitem__)
           return coords[start_index:] + coords[:start_index]

       polygon = orient(polygon)
       normalized_exterior = normalize_ring(polygon.exterior)
       normalized_interiors = list(map(normalize_ring, polygon.interiors))
       return Polygon(normalized_exterior, normalized_interiors)


   normalize(poly1).almost_equals(normalize(poly3))  # True
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is there a way to shift the starting point of a polygon? Aligning the points in order first will make the current equals_exact to work.

Comment: @ZL-Arctic There is no pretty solution for that in Shapely. You'd have to write some code for that. I'll add it later to the post, but for now, if you want to experiment, you can take some inspiration from [here](https://github.com/lycantropos/orient/blob/cdb22279816d61a7045c636e989b8c3d41cbac7f/tests/utils.py#L66).

Comment: This repo is very relevant to what I need here. Thanks.